# jquery error before getting grid data on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on mvc 4 application.
I have one `grid` on which i'm showing `employee status` when i change any record status.

> my controller method gets called correctly and change the status of employee.

but for a while for inconsistent scenario i'm getting following jquery error as this is customize,
but I see this error of only 1 sec and as page refreshed its gone and status is correctly changed but why i'm getting this error on PROD?

:(

It seems an jquery exception but could not able to catch this.
please guide me.

code for grid

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $("#@(Model.ID + "_Grid")");
        var popup = $(grid).closest(".popup_block");

        var popupHeight = parseInt(window.sessionStorage.currentpopupheight);

        //setting max height for grid
        if (popup.length > 0) {
            $(grid).css("max-height", popupHeight - 180);
            $(grid).css("overflow-y", "auto");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line looks incorrect:

```
var grid = $("#@(Model.ID + "_Grid")");
```

If `_Grid` is a variable coming from somewhere else, it should probably look like this:

```
var grid = $("#@(Model.ID " + _Grid + ")");
```

Unless if I'm mistaken and some values are being spit out by the server first, you had your `+` sign in the wrong spot.